# How to sort and then pull a specific group of objects from a mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm currently pulling every embedded object, that matches the given filters, from my mongodb collection. I then sort these and then .slice them to get the 10 objects the user actually needs depending on which page they are on, it looks like this.

```
const data = await EachWay.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$data"
    },
    {
        $match: filters
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "bookmaker": 1,
            "sport": 1,
            "data": 1
        }
    }
])

const start_index = (current_page - 1) * posts_per_page // included in results
const end_index = current_page * posts_per_page // won't be included in results

const shortened = data.sort((a, b) => {
    if(Number(a.data.rating) < Number(b.data.rating)){
        return 1
    } else if(Number(a.data.rating) > Number(b.data.rating)){
        return -1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}).slice(start_index, end_index).map(item => {
    let result = item.data
    
    result.bookmaker = item.bookmaker
    result.sport = item.sport
    return result
})
```

If the user is on page 3, this will get the 21st to the 30th post.

I feel like this is inefficient, as I'm having to pull every matching post from the database first, in some cases this can be 100,000 posts and then I only end up sending the client 10 of these. Is there a way to sort the embedded objects and pull the 21st-30th items from the database before returning the items?

Comment: The best approach is to query the documents in the range you expect the user to require, keep the cursor and using logic in your app decide which documents to display and returning only that portion of the cursor set.  In doing so, only one query is submitted to the database.  Sorting is best suited on the database because it can use indexes.  Try not to sort on the client (application).

Comment: If you cannot manage a cursor in your application, then consider using `skip()` and `limit()` query options. - https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/aggregation/ and https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/AggregationCursor.html#skip